# How to fix this Error with JAVA Rest Assure

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, rest-assured

I am building Java REST API with tests. The API runs perfectly and I don't have any issue with it.  The errors I am getting are in the testing part.

The tests uses Rest Assure library.

This is the test code
It is simply requesting (GET) google.com and checking whether the response status is 200 or not.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.List;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class DemoApplicationTests {

    static List<Integer> usersIds;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
        given().when().get("http://www.google.com").then().statusCode(200);
    }

}
```

### Pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hatim.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hatim</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

at com.hatim.demo.DemoApplicationTests.someTest(DemoApplicationTests.java:13) <27 internal calls>
```

When I comment out this code

```java
given().when().get("http://www.google.com").then().statusCode(200);
```

The error does away.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue currently is not fixed. See [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248) bug report for details.
It seams that JDK14 tries to load a constructor from `org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7` using Reflection, but the constructor does not exist for JDK14.
This is also because Java publishes a new major version every 6 months!

A solution might be to downgrade your major version to JDK13, or to the LTS version that will be supported [until 2026](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html).
Another solution might be to wait until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading to JDK 11 solved this issue for me

Comment: We shouldn't downgrade JDK to 11 as it is reaching end of life which is on Sep, 2023. Rather we need to find a solution to the existing problem with  the existing jdk version if jdk version is greater than jdk11.